# Passing reference to "this" anonymous outer function to passed inner function

Tags: javascript, function, namespaces, scope

For the sake of maintaining a namespace, I have code that looks something like this:

```
MyNamespace = function() {
    var foo;
    //other private vars

    //some private functions

    //return certain functions which will be publicly called through MyNamespace
    return {
        "pubFunc1": function() {/*do stuff*/}
    }
}
```

I'd like one of my public functions to be able to take a function as a parameter. The function being passed in would look something like this:

```
function(state) {
    //do something with the passed in state
}
```

This function would be passed into the first anonymous function. From there, as implied by the parameter, the first anonymous function would pass its state (with `this`) to the function that was just passed in. The problem I run into is that the `this` of an anonymous function refers to the global `window`, not to the anonymous function.

What I really need is the ability to pass in a function and give it full access to the private variables and functions within my namespace function. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure how/where you want to call which function, but if you want to determine which value `this` refers to, use `.call` or `.apply`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call. Of course you cannot access variables that are not in scope, that is just not possible.

Comment: The value of `this` is determined by HOW a function is called.  For us to help you, we need to see exactly how you're calling the function that you want to control `this` for before we can make a specific suggestion, but you will probably want to use `.call()` in order to set the `this` pointer as desired.  Private variables are only going to be accessible to functions whose code is actually inside the scope where the variables live.  Instance variables can be accessed just fine if you set `this` properly so the properties of that object can be referenced using `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript uses lexical scoping, that is, only functions physically located inside an outer function have access to its scope (`var`s). There's no way to make function's `var`s accessible for any function defined outside.

So your only option to make "private" vars into "protected" properties and pass the properties bag to the callback:

```
 MyNamespace = function() {
    return {
        _foo: "something",
        _bar: "else",
        pubFunc1: function(callback) {
             callback(this._foo, this._bar) //or
             callback(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this allow syntax such as `MyNamespace._foo = "something else"`? If it does, as I'd suspect, then previously private variables would be able to be influenced by sources outside of the public functions. In any case, I am marking your answer correct as it clarifies that `var`s defined in a function cannot be made accessible for functions defined outside, which is what I was looking to do.

Comment: @Rhitakorrr: there's no concept of "private" and "public" properties in javascript. Every property is accessible from everywhere.

Comment: Valid point. I end up (wrongly) using that terminology sometimes as a descriptor of scope in relation to other things. So, to phrase that better, would `_foo` and `_bar` then be accessible to things outside of the namespace through `MyNamespace._foo = "changed value"`? What I meant by "private" by the way was that those variables, when not in the return statement,  were inaccessible outside the scope of the function being called and assigned to `myNamespace`.